# SQL Window function with Case stmnt

Tags: sqlite, window-functions

I am trying to find out which trips are DNP and which are NP [condition : if max(oda) in a trip is greater than 2, it is DNP else NP]. The below quote is giving me DNP for all trips. I am not sure what's the error here.

```
with xyz as
 (select cnote ,DATE(dispatch_time) as final_date,bp_id , trip_id ,SUBSTR(serviceability,5,1)  as oda
from oda_trip_data otd ),
sneh as
 (select  *,
max(oda) over(partition by trip_id order by oda asc range BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING and UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as oda_trip_wise
from xyz
where final_date between '2019-05-01' and '2019-05-31')
select cnote,final_date,bp_id,trip_id,oda,
case when oda_trip_wise > 2 then 'DNP' else 'NP' end as trip_category
from sneh
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for editing this. Can you share the loop hole as well?